# Adding values to an Associative array

Tags: php

I'm tring to add new values to an associative array dynamically and I need your help.
Here is a simple example :

```
$a = array();
$a["name"]= "n1";
$a["age"]= "age1";
$a["name"]= "n2";
$a["age"]= "age2";
```

The result is:
Array (2){["name"]=>string(2) "n2" ["age"]=>string(4) "age2" }

I want to add The first age and name and the second age and name to the array. What can I do??

Comment: Array key name can't same for all .Here name,age repeating. use subarray

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to maintain name <=> age relationship :

```
$a = array();
$a[] = array("name"=>"n1","age"=>"age1");
$a[] = array("name"=>"n2","age"=>"age2");
```

---

**UPDATE** : usage example below :

```
foreach ($a as $assoc) {
    echo $assoc["name"],' is ',$assoc["age"],'.<br />';
}
```

Comment: In this way, how can I get the values using foreach?

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = array();
array_push($a, array("name"=>"n1","age"=>"age1"));
array_push($a, array("name"=>"n2","age"=>"age2"));
```

[array_push](https://www.php.net/array_push)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array();
$a["name"][]= "n1";
$a["age"][]= "age1";
$a["name"][]= "n2";
$a["age"][]= "age2";
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @A.Singh What are you talking about?

Comment: This generates different result. Thank you anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do by this way

```
$a = array(
  array(
      'name' => 'n1',
      'age'  => 'age1'
  ),
  array(
      'name' => 'n2',
      'age'  => 'age2'
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's *very easy and simple*, you can do whatever you want with arrays!! Any doubts? Here you go:

```
$a = array();
if(is_array($a) && i_can_answer())
{
    $keys = array('age', 'name');
    $anotherArray = array();
    if(is_array($anotherArray ) && i_know_multi_dimensional_arrays())
    {
        array_push($anotherArray, array("+18", "ILovePHP"));
        $result1 = array_combine($keys, $anotherArray);
    }
    $otherAnotherArray = array();
    if(is_array($otherAnotherArray) && i_am_not_tired())
    {
        array_push($otherAnotherArray , array("+18", "ILovePHP"));
        $result2 = array_combine($keys, $otherAnotherArray);
    }
    $a = array_merge($result1, $result2);
}
print_r($a); //// hoooorrraaaaaaaaaay
```